# Add application content to bugreport

Tags: android, frameworks, android-source

I'm working on custom AOSP project (AOSP 13).

I have added custom Android app in AOSP as privileged app. this app generates logs file in it's private space

```
/data/data/com.myapp/files/
```

Since it's a user build user can't access this log files.

Is there any way to add this log files in

> adb bugreport

?, I am able to do necessary changes in AOSP code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to include data in an Android bugreport from an Android app is to expose a public ContentProvider that implements the `dump` method, for example:

```
public class MyBugReportDataProvider extends ContentProvider {
    @Override
    public void dump(FileDescriptor fd, PrintWriter writer, String[] args) {
        if (!DumpUtils.checkDumpPermission(getContext(), TAG, writer)) {
            return;
        }

        writer.println("Stuff to include in bug reports");
    }
}
```

Make sure the provider is exported, as an example:

```
<provider
    android:name=".MyBugReportDataProvider"
    android:authorities="com.myapp.mybugreportdataprovider"
    android:multiprocess="false"
    android:singleUser="true"
    android:exported="true"/>
```

You will see the following in bug reports now:

```
PROVIDER ContentProviderRecord{x u0 com.myapp/.MyBugReportDataProvider} pid=99
    Client:
      Stuff to include in bug reports
```